# save array to a file - only values

Tags: php

I'm using this approach:

```
$s = array("one","two","three");
file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($s, true)."\n");
```

the file.txt output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
)
```

I want output to be just values like this:

```
one
two
three
```

How can be this done?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
$s = array("one","two","three");
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode("\n",$s));
```

Check live demo : https://eval.in/904966

It outputs as

```
one
two
three
```